# How to have a database counter that resets monthly?

Tags: sql, database, counter, reset

I have an application that needs to generate an unique identifier per item, this identifier is a mix of some initials, the date and 4 digits that increment for each new item. The tricky part is that the last 4 digits should reset monthly.

As an example, lets say we have UID **"SP-20121218-0001"**, the last 4 digits **"0001"** will increment up until January, and then the first item created in January should have **"SP-20130101-0001"**.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a quick thought (probably not the optimal solution), but what about a counter with additional fields for year and month, and you just increment the counter of the current `(year, month)`? Once a month or so, you could tidy up old months or even keep them to track how many UIDs you have generated in that month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a table with fields Year, Month, CurrentCount. write a stored procedure that selects a row for the current year and month, if it does not exists creates it and increments the number.

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like the perfect use case for a stored function.

In postgresql you would do this by having a sequence and then using a function to select a value from the sequence in combination with working out the current date and when the date turned over, resetting the sequence.

The best way though would be to not bother resetting the sequence and to just go with a unique number supplemented by the date.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to base the last 4 digits on a database sequence and then have a separate process that will reset that database sequence when a new month starts.